# npm installation warnings, Invalid version, no description etc

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I'm having the following warnings in command line:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN Invalid version: "x.0.0"
npm WARN myFirstAngular2Project No description
npm WARN myFirstAngular2Project No repository field.
npm WARN myFirstAngular2Project No README data
npm WARN myFirstAngular2Project No license field.
```

Help Please! :(

Comment: show your `package.json` file. or copy it form `angular.io quckstart` module and follow steps.

Comment: Please share package.json

Answer (score -1):

Package.json:

```
{
"name": "angulartypescript.com",
  "version": "x.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.X.X",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.X.X",
    "@angular/core":  "2.X.X",
    "@angular/http":  "2.X.X",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.X.X",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.X.X",
    "@angular/router":  "2.X.X",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.X.X",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.X.X",
    "systemjs": "X.X.X",
    "core-js": "x.x.x",
    "reflect-metadata": "x.x.x",
    "rxjs": "x.x.x",
    "zone.js": "x.x.x",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "x.x.x",
    "bootstrap": "x.x.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "x.x.x",
    "lite-server": "x.x.x",
    "typescript": "x.x.x",
    "typings":"x.x.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: Refer package.json from here- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files